# 2012 Honda Civic Hybrid Stereo System Unable to Reset Bluetooth

Tags: honda, civic, audio, bluetooth

I paired my Android smartphone with the car's stereo system. Everything worked fine for a couple of months, until one day I accidentally deleted the car on my phone's bluetooth settings page.

Now the car is unable to pair with any new phones, and all settings in all the menus are greyed out. How do I do a hard reset of the stereo system?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does your owner's manual have info? Tried Honda customer support online or call center? Tried disconnecting the radio for a complete power removal as a hard reset? There are usually two power sources; one is switched power, the other unswitched to keep presets and clock alive with ignition off. Disconnecting all wiring connections to the radio should perform a reset back to factory defaults.